# JSF which scope? Navigate from List to detail

Tags: scope

I´m searching for 2 hours but I don´t find any solution for my problem:

1) I have a list with 100 entries. This list contains also a link which redirect me to the detail page. I use for this list @ViewScoped

2) Which JSF should I use for the detailPage.jsf ? @SessionScoped works but this is not correct in my eyes. Because you could also open in some tabs more than one item from the list. If you would like to remove or edit the item in the detailPage.jsf you change maybe the wrong item.
This mean I need also @ViewScoped in the detailPage.jsf but this doesn´t work.

Can you help me?
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewScoped for the backing bean of detailPage.jsf. It works for me; why did you say that it didn't work? See [this link](http://richard.grin.free.fr/itu-madagascar/tp/tp1/index.html#Affichage_des_d.c3.a9tails_d'un_client_lorsqu'on_clique_sur_une_ligne). Unfortunately the page is in French but you will have the code.